# Access a variable from another class when using broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I am using broadcast receiver for get network status.I am using this code

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

  public Boolean networkStatus=false;

  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(     ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE );
    Log.w("Network Status:",""+activeNetInfo);
    if ( activeNetInfo != null )
    {
      networkStatus=true;
      Toast.makeText( context, "Active Network Type : " + activeNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
    if( mobNetInfo != null )
    {
      networkStatus=true;
      Toast.makeText( context, "Mobile Network Type : " + mobNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
  }
```

But you know this is a another class and I have to access `networkStatus` variable from main activity class.How can I do this ?

Comment: Make `static` variable and access it in `BroadcastReceiver`.... what's wrong with it?

Comment: you can either make it public static or save/retrieve it via sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `networkStatus` as `public static` in the main Activity. Access it using, for example, `MainActivity.networkStatus`.